# Credit card number over Https

Tags: security, payment

I have a scenario where the credit card number is being sent over the wire (HTTPS) from application server to browser. Thus, doing a view source of the payment page would display the entire credit card number.

Is this really a security vulnerability ?  Since the data is sent over SSL(the entire flow after login is https and the page in question is 3rd or 4th one in the flow), there is no way for man in the middle to get this information. Also,I tested for session side jacking (getting the session id when user is on http and try to impersonate...) - the application is intelligent enough to prevent this attack.

I was thinking in the lines of adding a secure cookie in addition to not sending the entire credit card number over the wire, but is that an overkill ?

Comment: `Secure` cookies aren't particularly secure. Most sites just send the last four digits of the card number. What's wrong with that?

Comment: You could also use some extra encryption. Try in http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS, implemented properly (most browsers do, [check your server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377865/how-to-configure-openssl-in-a-secure-way-for-https/19382328#19382328)), provides complete end-to-end secure delivery of the data. There will be no man in the middle attacks.

We're also assuming your website is safe from cross site scripting attacks.

Still, it's best to show just the last four digits. This is for such cases as someone wanting to do their banking or shopping or whatever from a public location. It prevents those snooping over their shoulder from getting entire account numbers.

It's still an issue if someone want's to enter a new credit card (watch your back), but there's very little reason to show the entire credit card number once you've verified it. Let the customer name the account though, just in case they have more than one card with the same last 4 digits, plus for ease of use.